# Проблема при миграции Yii2 БД PostgreSQL на Openserver

Tags: php, yii2, postgresql

Пытаюсь применить миграцию базы на локальном хосте, отдаёт ошибку:

```
PHP Fatal Error 'yii\base\ErrorException' with message 'Class 'yii2mod\enum\helpers\BaseEnum' not found'

in D:\OSPanel\domains\server\server\common\models\enums\UserRole.php:11

Stack trace:
#0 [internal function]: yii\base\ErrorHandler->handleFatalError()
#1 {main}
```

Клонировал проект из Bitbucket репозитория. В него скопировал папку vendor из сборки advanced. Далле init 0. Создал БД Postgre. В конфиге всё корректно. При команде yii migrate падает с Fatal Error. Что делаю не так?

Comment: `скопировал папку vendor` поставьте нормальным способом. Через `composer install` скорей всего.

Comment: да, всё верно, помогло